# Getting a syntax error unexpected T_STRING for namespace line

Tags: php, syntax-error

Well, I keep getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /path/to/index.php on line 2

Googled my arse off and still nuthing, so far the index.php contains:

```
<?php
namespace Infire; # Line 2
...
```

I am using PHP 5.1

Any ideas?

Comment: is your php version `>=5.3.0` ?

Comment: Check your PHP version. Only the second line and above is interesting for the error.

Answer (score 10):

The PHP namespace is only supported in **PHP 5.3+** version

> Check this [PHP 5.3.0 Release Announcement](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php)

Answer (score 0):

I've found namespaces introduced in PHP 5.3 to suffer from multiple usability problems due to performance trade-offs, limitations of PHP's parser, collisions with other PHP features and unfortunate design decisions.