# what to use in place of namespace in php 5.2

Tags: php, namespaces

What do I use in place of namespace for older versions of php 5.2 and earlier
using this code below it gives an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

```
<?php

namespace Aws\Tests\CloudWatch;

use Aws\CloudSearch\CloudSearchClient;

class CloudSearchClientTest extends \Guzzle\Tests\GuzzleTestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers Aws\CloudSearch\CloudSearchClient::factory
     */
    public function testFactoryInitializesClient()
    {
        $client = CloudSearchClient::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'foo',
            'secret' => 'bar',
            'region' => 'us-east-1'
        ));

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureV4', $this->readAttribute($client, 'signature'));
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials', $client->getCredentials());
        $this->assertEquals('https://cloudsearch.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', $client->getBaseUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Namespace support is available since `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650836/getting-a-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-for-namespace-line this page says php 5.3

Comment: The OP is clearly asking about **5.2** - in both the title, and the question.

Comment: Hi aav, welcome to SO.

Comment: You can remove `namespace` with `use` keyword and can include classes manually before you use or can use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), in other words, you have to refactor the code but better to update the `php`.

Comment: How many files/classes/interfaces you have in your current project to change, if it's 3/4 then you may re-code these files and maybe manually use `include` to add before you use any class.

Comment: would i include the php within the cloudwatch folder, i see a php called cloudwatchclient.php is that similar to namespace

Comment: include 'Aws\CloudSearch\CloudSearchClient.php'; is this the same as use?

Comment: okay i think i figured out how to rewrite these, each use is the same as include

Comment: Great - if you've found a solution, you can answer and accept your own answer, so other people with this problem can see what you did.

Comment: do i just get rid of namespace when changing use to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're trying to use here (looks like the Amazon AWS SDK?) is not compatible with PHP 5.2. You will need to upgrade to PHP 5.3 or later to use it.

Comment: No - that's not what [the `use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) means at all, actually.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for your help, i found one for an older php i will try to use that

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just cannot use these namespaced classes in php 5.2 code.

Comment: do i just get rid of namespace when changing use to include?